# PHP Editing JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i want to edit my JSON array after i check the elements in php. I mean firstly i need to check elements in JSON if it doesn't exist i want to create new one. If it already created i want to add it as new element. For example;

```
    { 
    "fruits": [
            {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin C",
        "Name": "Apple",
        }
        {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin B",
        "Name": "Banana",
        }
        {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin D",
        "Name": "Watermelon",
        }
        {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin C",
        "Name": "Orange",
        }
        {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin C",
        "Name": "Mandarin",
        }
     ]
 }
```

lets say these are my inputs. I want to check every Vitamin object and if it has already created i want to make it like this;

```
    { 
    "fruits": [
            {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin C",
        "Name": ["Apple", "Orange", "Mandarin"]
        }
        {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin B",
        "Name": "Banana",
        }
        {
        "Vitamin": "Vitamin D",
        "Name": "Watermelon",
        }
     ]
 }
```

Should i use array_key_exists? I have no clue what should i do about this. SHould i create JSON every time i enter an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you're trying to group on the key "Vitamin"

To do so, I would do something like that :

```
/**
 * Group an array based on a "key column" and a "value column".
 * @param array $json       The array to transform.
 * @param string $keyCol    The column name from wich we will group
 * @param string $valCol    The value that we need to  group
 * @return array            The array grouped on the keycol.
 */
function groupJsonOnKey(array $json, $keyCol, $valCol) {
    $groupedArray = [];
    foreach ($json as $val) {
        $key = $val[$keyCol];
        if (!isset($groupedArray[$key]))
            $groupedArray = (object) [$keyCol => $key, $valCol => []];
        $groupedArray[$key]->$valCol[] = $val[$valCol];
    }
    return $groupedArray;
}

//We load the data and parse it to an array
$jsonData = json_decode("DECODE YOUR JSON TO AN ARRAY", true);

$groupedArray = groupJsonOnKey($jsonData['fruits'], 'Vitamin', 'Name');

//Now we recreate the expected output
$newData = new stdClass();
$newData->fruits = array_values($groupedArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for brief explanation. I got the points now. But i get inputs from ajax request. So where should i add items? I guess i should push new json to an array. Am i right?

Comment: If you could detail a bit the flowchart of your process, I could help your further more. I guess you're sending your items from the front-end(Javascript) and sending it to the backend to save it in a database or a file?